# How to enable Expression Language in the NiFi's custom processor?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have my custom NiFi processor. I have implemented it according to the tutorials, i.e. it:

- `extends AbstractProcessor`;
- has some `PropertyDescriptor` fields;
- overrides `onTrigger(...)`;
- etc.

So, it's a working custom processor.

However, when I try to add Dynamic Properties (from the NiFi UI) and use Expression Language in the Property's value (like Property: X, Value: `${flowfileattr}`), it complains as:

> X validated against ${flowfileattr} is invalid because X is not a supported property or has no validator associated with it.

How can I enable EL as a property value in the NiFi custom processor?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you must set expressionLanguageSupported on your PropertyDescription.Builder

```
@Override
protected PropertyDescriptor getSupportedDynamicPropertyDescriptor(String propertyDescriptorName) {
    return new PropertyDescriptor.Builder()
            .required(false)
            .name(propertyDescriptorName)
            .addValidator(StandardValidators.createAttributeExpressionLanguageValidator(AttributeExpression.ResultType.STRING, true))
            .dynamic(true)
            .expressionLanguageSupported(ExpressionLanguageScope.FLOWFILE_ATTRIBUTES)
            .build();
}
```

After that definition, when you read your property you must use this method.

```
context.getProperty(dynamicPropertyName).evaluateAttributeExpressions(requestFlowFile).getValue();
```

You can sample
[InvokeHTTP](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/main/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/InvokeHTTP.java) processor.